# How to get data into a CTE and do an update

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Using MS SQL Server, I want to:

1. Get data from my application
2. Perform preprocessing
3. Update a table

Steps 1 and 3 are giving me problems.

Simplifying the problem to its essence, my existing data looks like:

```
+--------+-------+
|  Item  | Usage |
+--------+-------+
| Part A |    10 |
| Part B |    15 |
| Part C |     8 |
+--------+-------+
```

and an example of the source data is:

```
+--------+
|  Item  |
+--------+
| Part A |
| Part B |
| Part B |
| Part B |
| Part A |
| Part A |
+--------+
```

My over all plan is to import the data into a CTE, do the preprocessing, then do an update.

Regarding getting the data, since "INTO" is not allowed in a CTE, how can I get the source data into the CTE.  Or some other approach not using a CTE better?

Preprocessing is straightforward.  Here is my SQL:

```
WITH MyData (Item, NewUsage)
AS
(
    <Somehow get the data>
    SELECT Item, Count(*) as NewUsage
    FROM Items
    GROUP BY Item
)
UPDATE Items
SET Usage = Usage + b.NewUsage
FROM Items as a JOIN MyData as b ON a.Item = b.Item;
```

The update is updating all the rows in Items by 1 instead of using the NewUsage column.

How do I get my data (into the CTE?) and how to write the SQL so it works properly?

Comment: You are using `COUNT` and it's getting 1 as the count for each item from the first table so it's updating by one. If you want to use the usage value then you need to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: I think you have the wrong idea about what a [`CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is. For the most part (unless you're using recursion or stacking, which you're not) it's just a sub-query.

Comment: @Larnu I don't normally do that but this post was too long already so I cut some corners.

Comment: @Susang  The SELECT query uses the second table and I want the Count of the number of times each part appears in that list..